# ResultSetMappingBuilder and name conflict in mapper

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got entity A with two ManyToOne relations. And both join columns with same name. When I am creating query based on entity A with ResultSetMappingBuilder and setting this entity to method `addRootEntityFromClassMetada` it results in `InvalidArgumentException` `The column 'created_by' conflicts with another column in the mapper.`.

Here is quick sample for entity A

```
/**
 * @var B
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="B")
 * @JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $a;

/**
 * @var C
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="C")
 * @JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $b;
```

How can I avoid to conflict? I tried almost everything that I found on stack. But there are not many problems with this.

Doctrine  2.6.1

Thanks for you answers,
Michal

Comment: Sadly I no longer have access to code where I've faced the issue but I think I worked this around aliasing conflicting columns. There's also a chance I had to manually map RSM due to this.